# Как проксировать запросы?

Tags: http, proxy

Есть продакшн сайт и тест,
мне нужно подменить все запросы с prod.site.com?param1=1 на test.site.com?param1=1 и протестировать.
При этом когда я залил продакшен - я править не могу код, а мне важно оттестировать и подменить данные. Какие программы решают подобные задачи?

Comment: А не проще ли было адрес сайта вынести в настройки окружения?

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/189027